# 'multithreading' setInterval functions (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm tasked with creating a progress bar (actually, a timer that looks like a progress bar) that will be triggered on a click event. I need multiple bars as a person may click on multiple elements that will trigger the progress bar. This is the script I have now:

```
function createPbar(IDofpBar, timeOut, timeIncrement ) {

            ...grab dom elements and do the math...

    i=0;
    var newWidth = 0;   

    var x = setInterval(function(){
        theBar.style.width = newWidth+"px"
        newWidth = newWidth + bIncrement;
        if (i == counter) {
            clearInterval(x);
        }
        i++
    }, timeIncrement*1000);

}
```

This works fine until I have more than one on the page at a time. When I trigger the second one, it affects the first one. I'm guessing it's due to reassigning the variables each time I trigger a new progress bar.

Is there a way to isolate the variables per call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `var` to declare variables within the scope of the current function, rather than in the global scope. You're missing a `var` before the `i=0;` statement. I don't see the code that initializes `theBar`, but you might be missing a `var` there, too.

```
function createPbar(IDofpBar, timeOut, timeIncrement ) {

    /* ...grab dom elements and do the math... */

    var theBar = ...,
        i=0,
        newWidth = 0;

    var x = setInterval(function(){
        theBar.style.width = newWidth+"px"
        newWidth = newWidth + bIncrement;
        if (i == counter) {
            clearInterval(x);
        }
        i++
    }, timeIncrement*1000);
}
```

Just in case: [`var` keyword @ MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

Comment: argh! Yep. That was the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Matt's answer is correct, but I'll expand on it a bit further.

In javascript assigning a variable without using the `var` keyword creates the variable in the *global scope*.  In your current code this means that all instances of your progress bar are going to be referencing and accessing the same instance of `i`.

By using the `var` keyword to declare variables inside of a function, it declares the variable to have *local scope* and makes it only accessible from within the function.  This allows you to have independent versions of the variables used in your function.

This is a gotcha which I often find myself having to go back and fix when I forget.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation!

Comment: It's not correct though. Undeclared variables are created as properties of the global object *when they are assigned values*, attempting to use them before then will create a reference error like "i is not defined".

Declaring variables means they are available before code execution begins, preventing such errors.